# Multithreading in a hashmap entry loop - Executor service (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a map (`HashMap<String, Map<String,String> mapTest`) in which I have a loop that does several operations.

```
HashMap<String, Map<String, String> mapTest = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Object> testFinals = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : mapTest.entrySet()) {

    // in here I do a lot of things, like another for loops, if's, etc.

    //the final juice to get from here is that in each time the loop is executed I have this:

    List<Object> resultExp = methodXYZ(String, String, String);

    testFinals.addAll(resultExp);
}
```

**- In here, I have to wait before I proceed, since I need the full testFinals filled to advance.**

Now, what I need to do is:

1 - This mapTest can have like 400 rows to iterate from.

**I want to schedule like 4 threads, and assign like 100 rows of that FOR cycle to thread 1, the next 100 rows of the mapTest to thread 2, and so on.**

Already tryed a few solutions, like this one:

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

while(...) {

  taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());

}

taskExecutor.shutdown();

try {

  taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

  ...

}
```

but I can't adapt this correctly or a similar working solution to what I have now, with that map iteration.

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap is not a thread safe data structure.**

When using concurrent, consider that the threads must obtain, hold and relinquish locks on a variable.

This is done at field level -not content.

On short ... The hasmap is locked for access  y a specific thread. Not some random entry.

Comment: I've tryed a solution where basically I've used a convert on FOR LOOP to use stream.paralell, but I don't see a way to define the number of threads for example.

Do you have any code block suggestion to help me out more?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrent-map#:~:text=And%2C%20importantly%2C%20HashMap%20is%20not,it%20is%20not%20very%20efficient.

Comment: see above at 3.1. Thread-Safety